# How to add 3 sets of JavaScript in the header

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to run three sets of JS code in my header tag, however, I can only seem to run two at a time with the following code (see below)...

(this code below works perfectly fine on it's own)

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.frhdesigns.com/lightbox2.04/css/lightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.frhdesigns.com/lightbox2.04/js/prototype.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.frhdesigns.com/lightbox2.04/js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.frhdesigns.com/jquery-vertical-scroll/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         jQuery.noConflict();
    </script>
    <script src="http://www.frhdesigns.com/jquery-vertical-scroll/js/jquery.localscroll-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://www.frhdesigns.com/jquery-vertical-scroll/js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.frhdesigns.com/lightbox2.04/js/lightbox.js">     
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery.localScroll.defaults.axis = 'y';
            jQuery.localScroll();
        });
    </script>
```

...Now when I add the third set of code to the mix (3rd set of js code below) which is a code for fading images, I can't seem to get all three to work together when I view the page. I know JS is all about order...but I don't know the order...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="_fade_in/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_fade_in/js/custom.js"></script>
```

thanks!

---

**ok.  where should I place this line of code**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="_fade_in/js/custom.js"></script> 

**in the following sequence?**

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.frhdesigns.com/lightbox2.04/js/prototype.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.frhdesigns.com/lightbox2.04/js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="_fade_in/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
</script>

<script src="http://www.frhdesigns.com/jquery-vertical-scroll/js/jquery.localscroll-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.frhdesigns.com/jquery-vertical-scroll/js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.frhdesigns.com/lightbox2.04/js/lightbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery.localScroll.defaults.axis = 'y';
            jQuery.localScroll();
        });
</script>
```

Comment: where is the other code?

Comment: does custom.js have any errors?

Comment: There are two versions of jquery in your header. a version 1.4.2 and a 1.3.2. use one or another. not sure what version jquery your fading images plugin.  also it would really help to accept answers to your previous questions.

Comment: so i partially understand. I took out version jquery version 1.3.2., but how do I update jquery version 1.4.2 so it works with the fading images function?

Comment: @Freddie it depends on the plugins...are all your jQuery plugins compatible w/ 1.4.2 or 1.3.2?

Comment: They seem to be. I now have the lightbox and the localscroll pluggin working fine with jquery version 1.3.2 (which was the version used for the fading images).  But the fading images plugin still won't work...I feel it's because I'm not placing this line of code in it's proper place.  <script type="text/javascript" src="_fade_in/js/custom.js"></script>

Comment: put it after the `jQuery.noConflict()` @Freddie you should accept answers that help you with your questions so people would want to help you in the future

Comment: how do i accept answers? Is it in my settings? I just created an account here two days ago.

Comment: yes, basically, go to the answers and there should be a checkmark below each vote count and check it to make it green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the names of your files, it looks like you are loading jQuery twice.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.frhdesigns.com/jquery-vertical-scroll/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_fade_in/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```

Get rid of the second jQuery include and update the first to the particular version you need (if it isn't already).

Comment: ok.  where should I place the following code <script type="text/javascript" src="_fade_in/js/custom.js"></script>

Comment: It needs to be placed after any scripts it relies on. If there is jQuery code in that script, place it after the `jQuery.noConflict()` block like others have said. It's similar to building a house. In order for walls to be put up, there first needs to be a floor. In order for a floor to be put in, there needs to be a foundation. So you include the foundation first, then the floor, then the walls.

Comment: Understandable, however the fade images plugin is still the only function not working when I place <script type="text/javascript" src="_fade_in/js/custom.js"></script> after the the jQuery.noConflict() block.

Comment: @Freddie are you using chrome or firefox's firebug? go into the developer's console and let us know the error.  also, can you link us a direct link to your custom.js file?

Comment: @kjy112 I'm not using firebug at all (should I install it? I'm just a graphic designer)  here's a direct link - http://www.frhdesigns.com/_fade_in/js/custom.js

Comment: @Freddie install it. hmmm try replace the `$` in custom.js with `jQuery`

Comment: The `custom.js` is looking for an element with a class of `menu`. Is that the correct selector for you html?

Comment: @Rfvgyhn -   yes, ".menu" in my custom.js file is correct in my html.

@kjy112 -  this is the error message I see in the "DOM" section using firebug - "Error: "throw $continue" is deprecated, use "return" instead"  I have no idea what it means

Comment: @Freddie switch out jquery1.3.2 and use 1.4.2 see if it'll fix it.  i think your other jquery plugin requires 1.4.2

Comment: Didn't work.  here's a link to all the javascript text files in my header tag, maybe I'm not explaining everything I need to...  http://www.frhdesigns.com/_test_.html    (view page source)

Comment: @Freddie in your custom.js change every `$` to `jQuery`

Comment: @ kjy112 It works!  I'm a schmuck for not doing that when you first said it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable jQuery.noConflict(); for jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery.noConflict();

     // Use jQuery instead of $
     jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       jQuery("div").hide();
     });

     //  prototype codes

     //  scriptaculous
</script>
```